# Add/Remove iron-selected class based on the paper-tab selection

Tags: polymer, lit-element, iron-pages

I have started learning Polymer & lit-element and was working on active & inactive status grid where i have used paper-tabs with iron-pages.

Question: When I switch between the **`paper-tabs`**, the **`iron-selected`** class is adding to the **`paper-tab`** links but not getting added to the **`iron-pages`** content.

How to make the **`iron-selected`** class work with the **`iron-pages`** content?

Any solution would be great!

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.currentPage = 0;
}
render() {
return html `
<div class="card">
    <paper-tabs scrollable selected=${this.currentPage}>
        <paper-tab>Tab 1</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>Tab 2</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>Tab 3</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>
    <iron-pages selected=${this.currentPage}>
        <div>some story for tab 1</div>
        <div>some story for tab 2</div>
        <div>some story for tab 3</div>
    </iron-pages>
</div>
`;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Polymer, lit-html doesn't have a two way data binding mechanism so you have to take care of updating the `currentPage` property in the [`selected-changed` event](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/paper-tabs/elements/paper-tabs#event-selected-changed):

```js
render() {
  return html`
    <div class="card">
      <paper-tabs scrollable
                  selected=${this.currentPage /* This is unidirectional */}
                  @selected-changed=${e => this.currentPage = e.detail.value}>
        <paper-tab>Tab 1</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>Tab 2</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>Tab 3</paper-tab>
      </paper-tabs>
      <iron-pages selected=${this.currentPage}>
        <div>some story for tab 1</div>
        <div>some story for tab 2</div>
        <div>some story for tab 3</div>
      </iron-pages>
    </div>
  `;
}
```